# Stat -c command in UNIX

Tags: linux, stat

I am using the [stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) commands to show information of all files in a directory, by using the below commands in a script:

```
  stat -c"%n|%s|%y" <FOLDER>/* | sed -r 'h; s/\|.*$//; s/^/wc -l </e; G;     s/\n/|/; s/^([^|]*\|)([^|]*\|)/\2\1/; s/( [^ ]*){1}$//;s#/#|#'  > Stats.csv
```

It gives me file information in a pipe-delimited file, 
**Folder Name** | **File Name** | **Row counts** | **File Size** | **Date files arrived**

An example:

```
AVIL|Applicability_Master_100K.txt|100000|6264377|2019-05-23 12:51:45.454241257
AVIL|Vendor_Master_20190528.txt|22677|3950461|2019-05-29 13:49:43.465444584 
AVIL|Sales_Order_20190527.txt|15056|4328799|2019-05-29 13:50:03.670264272 
AVIL|Purchase_Order_20190529.txt|10110|1514505|2019-05-29 13:49:22.360588383
```

I want to change **Mb** to **MB** and get rid of milliseconds in the date column.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't already sized in MB? Files aren't generally sized in Mb - or is this purely fixing up an incorrect label?

Comment: du -h <filename> gives me 3.8M (human readable MB or can be GB)
du -k <filename> gives me 3860 (Mega bytes ? not sure)

i want to incorporate du -h <file name> in the above mentioned stats -c command

Comment: %w is not working for me it is showing " -- " in the date column, i am using x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that field four, File Size, is now in bytes (not Mb as originally stated in your original post), and you want that changed to MB (i.e., divided by 10^6)? If so, how many decimal points do you want to show? For example, the first line of your example has a value for File Size of 6,264,377 bytes; do you want that to show as 6MB, 6.3MB, 6.26MB, or some other value? Please click [edit] and revise the next to the last line of your question accordingly. Please do NOT click [Add Comment] as when more comments arrive, old comments are pushed off the screen.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last 10(ten) characters of the line, the milliseconds and period of the **Date files arrived** column, use [rev](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rev.1.html) and [cut](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) and add this at the end of your expression:

```
| rev | cut -c 10- | rev
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i am using stat -c"%n|%s|%y"  -- wondering if there is any way to pass %n or some other valuses -- number %s size (in MB or GB format) % y (date time only)

Comment: Here is the output
    AVIL|Applicability_Master_100K.txt|100000|6264377|2019-05-23 12:51:45.454241257
    AVIL|Vendor_Master_20190528.txt|22677|3950461|2019-05-29 13:49:43.465444584
   AVIL|Sales_Order_20190527.txt|15056|4328799|2019-05-29 13:50:03.670264272
   AVIL|Purchase_Order_20190529.txt|10110|1514505|2019-05-29 13:49:22.360588383